# How to call this function outside the function?

Tags: javascript

```
function firstFunction()
{
  stringWord = "Hello World";
  function secondFunction()//How to call this function in thirdfunction() ??
  {
    alert(stringWord);
  }
} 

function thirdFunction()
{
  run = setTimeout( ... , 5000);
}
```

Hi, I give up for this. Any one help me or have another way to call the function?

Comment: why dont you just take the second function outside?

Comment: i found this link useful http://hungred.com/how-to/tutorial-function-function-javascript/

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/#Nested_functions_and_closures i found this link. Maybe it is useful for you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 function firstFunction()
        {
          stringWord = "Hello World";
          this.secondFunction = function()//How to call this function in thirdfunction() ??
          {
            alert(stringWord);
          }
        }
        var instand = new firstFunction();
        function thirdFunction(){
            run = setTimeout( 'instand.secondFunction()', 5000);
        }
```

Hope this help.

Comment: It's great, it's running well. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
function firstFunction()
{
  stringWord = "Hello World";
  return function secondFunction()//How to call this function in thirdfunction() ??
  {
    alert(stringWord);
  };
}

secondFunction = firstFunction(); 

function thirdFunction()
{
  run = setTimeout( 'secondFunction()' , 5000);
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DRfzc/

Comment: Consider flagging it as the correct answer to the problem, then ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to call `secondFunction()` from outside `firstFunction()` without modifying `firstFunction()`. If that is acceptable keep reading...

Method 1: Modify `firstFunction()` to return a reference to `secondFunction()`:

```
function firstFunction() {
  stringWord = "Hello World";
  return function secondFunction() {
    alert(stringWord);
  }
}
// And then call `firstFunction()` in order to use the function it returns:
function thirdFunction() {
  run = setTimeout(firstFunction(), 5000);
}
// OR
var secondFunc = firstFunction();
function thirdFunction() {
  run = setTimeout(secondFunc, 5000);
}
```

Method 2: Have `firstFunction()` put a reference to `secondFunction()` in a variable accessible outside its scope:

```
var secondFunc;
function firstFunction() {
  stringWord = "Hello World";
  function secondFunction() {
    alert(stringWord);
  }
  window.secondFunc = secondFunction;  // to make a global reference, AND/OR
  secondFunc = secondFunc; // to update a variable declared in same scope
                           // as firstFunction()
}
firstFunction();
function thirdFunction() {
  run = setTimeout(secondFunc, 5000);
}
```

Note that with either method you have to actually *call* `firstFunction()` before trying to use the inner function.

Comment: This is VERY HELPED!! Thank you very much. I'm feeling good when I try this.

Answer (score 0):

```
var stringWord;
function firstFunction()
{
  stringWord = "Hello World";
  secondFunction();
} 

 function secondFunction()
  {
    alert(stringWord);
  }

function thirdFunction()
{
  run = setTimeout( 'secondFunction()' , 5000);
}
```